# How to add " and " around a number

Tags: python, pandas, csv, double-quotes

I use Python to create a text file, which is fed into a calculation APP. Due to the setting up of the calculation APP (which I cannot change), it persists that a number must be wrapped by double quote.

For example, when I open an existing text file used in the calculation APP from Notepad, I can see `"1"`. However, when I write from Python using `to_csv`, number will not be wrapped by double quote. I tried the folowing, but it gives me `"""1"""` instead of `"1"`. How can I get to the desired format in this case, please?

```
data['field_1'] = data['field_1'].astype(str)
data['field_1'] = '"' + data['field_1'] + '"'
data.to_csv("output.txt", index=False)
```

Comment: That is the expected quoting behavior for Python's default csv dialect. What csv dialect (i.e. quoting behavior) do you want as a whole?

Comment: @Brian What I need is to be able to wrap a number in "". Sorry not really familiar with the csv dialect thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can force quotes for all columns using the [`quoting`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) argument:

```
import csv
...
data.to_csv("output.txt", index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Edit: If you only want to quote *some* columns, you should explicitly add quotes, and disable automatic quoting using `QUOTE_NONE`:

```
data['field_1'] = '"' + data['field_1'] + '"'
data.to_csv("output.txt", index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```